# Keras, how to retrieve layers outputs in a custom training loop ? (more precisely in the *train_step* function)

Tags: keras

In the Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/) we see that it's possible to customize what happens during training after every batch, for instance if we want to compute our own loss, we can override the *train_step* function:

```
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute our own loss
            loss = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)
```

But, what if I want to use some outputs of some layers in order to compute a custom loss after every batch ?

Is there a way to have access to some layers outputs in the *train_step* function ?

Comment: what is the custom loss you want to apply?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I want to apply a policy gradient that uses the softmax (probabilities) of several layers (you can look for "policy gradient" here https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-architecture-search-nas-the-future-of-deep-learning-c99356351136)